# Change formatting of a posixct time series on an axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My x-axis series is a vector of POSIXct date values which contain a dummy year. Eg: "0000-04-20".

This is what I use to plot:
`ggplot(meterData, aes(DayMonth, kW, color = Installation)) + geom_point(alpha=1)`

What should I add so that my x axis labels do not include the year. They should include just the day and month.

Comment: `scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m-%d"))`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with POSIXct values

Comment: try `scale_x_datetime`. I missed the `POSIXct` part.